# Error on Rails ActiveRecord creation with :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In class

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
```

the attribute of similar_idea_ids & similar_ideas is asserted like this:

```
has_many :similar_idea_ids, :class_name => "SimilarIdea", :foreign_key => "idea_id"
has_many :similar_ideas, :through => :similar_idea_ids, :class_name => "Idea"
```

Then, when inserting with this code:

```
self.similar_ideas << idea unless self.id == idea.id
```

I've got error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for []:Array
```

Can anyone figure this out? Great thanks!

Comment: You are misusing has_many :through. Please carefully the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many). It will also help to post the full Idea and SimilarIdea models.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the other side of the code.

It's like:

class SimilarIdea < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :idea, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "idea_id"
    belongs_to :similar_idea, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "similar_idea_id"
end

Answer (score 0):

First off, as these are associations between two or more models, it would be helpful to see the associations from both or all directions. Is this a many to many association? A one to many?

Secondly, I don't believe you've declared your association correctly in the model (as bricker mentions in his comment).  It appears that you're trying to put an association on an attribute rather than on another model. This is not the intention of the mechanism. It's basically a way of simplifying how you declare and use models that have some relationship. A many to many being one of the more complex because it has a join table is especially simplified with these associations.

I would suggest that you read this fantastic [guide on ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: It's a many-to-many association. The code is like this:

class SimilarIdea < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :idea, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "idea_id" belongs_to :similar_idea, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "similar_idea_id" end

Comment: do you have an ActiveRecord for your join table?

Comment: Yes.

It's called SimilarIdea, as referred previously.

Comment: I've found it's the problem of naming ... for belongs_to :similar_idea has the same name as the class name "SimilarIdea".

This article helped me a lot.

http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2007/06/27/self-referential-many-to-many-relations-in-ruby-on-rails/